# Save email attachment based on the email originator and output folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I do not have knowledge of VBA and I have researched stack overflow but can not get it working. Basically I want to save all attachments (csv files) that are moved by rule to my folder 'Test' in outlook and save in my Documents.
The rule move emails with attachments.

When I set up the rule I do not have the option to use a macro as a rule (company requirements).

Please help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you. TL;DR: since you can't use VBA code, at least post what you've tried (maybe include some screen shots) setting up in your Outlook rules. Be sure to blank out any private info like e-mail addresses leaving the first char or two and the last so we can tell it's an email address, etc.

Comment: What do you mean company requirements?

Answer (score -1):

You could create a rule, refer to this link:

[How To Automatically Download/Save Attachments From Outlook To A Certain Folder?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html)

```
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"
```

This vba code is means where you want to save attachment. You could change this to your Documents folder URL.

Comment: When I set up the rule I do not have the option to use a macro as a rule (company requirements).

Comment: According to your comment, If you can't use a macro as rule, you might perform the vba code by yourselves in outlook "Developer". This only issue is you can't  save attachment to your folder automaticly. You could download attachments from specific folder in Outlook, You could refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994435/download-attachments-from-specific-folder-in-outlook