# How to download files from outlook using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, outlook, automation

I want to download the files from the particular folder in the outlook(take folder name as Files).

I receive files daily and want to download the latest one.
I would like to use PowerShell script that can go through emails in the Files folder and save the latest attachment by seeing the subject line(For eg if subject line contains "Daily files")into the folder "c:\Files"

I am new to this and have tried reviewing other comments, but not able to get the required code.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert powershell script saving outlook attachments to save them from not inbox but inbox subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181425/convert-powershell-script-saving-outlook-attachments-to-save-them-from-not-inbox)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you would like to download the attachments of Email from special folder in Outlook. I'm not sure that if you checked this link:

[How do I Save Outlook Attachments using Powershell?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/11218cf2-eb24-4110-967f-b29234064501/how-do-i-save-outlook-attachments-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)

However, you could also use the VBA code to achieve your needs. Please see the following link:

[Download attachments from specific folder in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994435/download-attachments-from-specific-folder-in-outlook)